# Use the Dapper to return the date if the value is in null basis

Tags: c#, dapper

how can I use Dapper to return the date if I have this field in NULL?

This is my method, only something is missing when I return the output to the method, see the picture .. I do not know what I'm doing wrong ..

My method:

```
    public DateTime GetArbeitStart(int userId)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = _ConnectionString;
            var output = connection.Query<DateTime>("select LPE_ArbeitStart from A_PERSONAL WHERE LPE_ID=" + userId).FirstOrDefault();

            return output == null ? new DateTime(2018, 1, 1);
        } 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you do in the situation where output isn't null?

Comment: You miss the "else" part... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: @john If it is a zero value, I want to return the date (2018,1,1)

Comment: @MaxB can you decorate me?

Comment: You should use different operator, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Comment: @John I need it if output query null, to return that date

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you seem to be trying to combine a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) with the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

I think you simply want the null coalescing operator:

```
return output ?? new DateTime(2018, 1, 1);
```

Or if you want the more verbose ternary operator:

```
return output == null ? new DateTime(2018, 1, 1) : output;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `else` part in a ternary operator

`return output === null ? new Date() : somethingElse;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative:

```
public DateTime GetArbeitStart(int userId)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = _ConnectionString;
        return connection.Query<DateTime>("select LPE_ArbeitStart from A_PERSONAL WHERE LPE_ID=" + userId)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(new DateTime(2018, 1, 1)).First();
    } 
}
```

I like that it's really declarative.